# CSS: reposition element on hover state but maintain clickable area position

Tags: css, hover, positioning

I'm trying to create the effect of a button that 'lifts' from the page when rolled over.

Using CSS, I have a block style `<a>` element that, when *hovered*, re-positions itself up and to the left **5px**, and a shadow is left behind:

```
a { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;    }

a:hover {
    top: -5px; left: -5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 5px 5px 2px;    }
```

**The problem:** When the `<a>` block jumps 5px away from the cursor during the hover, the cursor is no longer actually hovering over the block and the block then jumps back when the cursor is moved only slightly thereafter.

*How can I maintain the original hover area so that the element doesn't keep jumping back and forth when the cursor is only slightly moved?*

I'd like to avoid adding superfluous container elements to my code if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using a superfluous element (a transparent image or a parent div of large size). When user hovers on the image, using a descendent/child selector you ask the child elements to 'jump'. This may be possible only with the latest browsers. If you are looking at cross browser compatibility, using javascript may be the right approach.

Comment: Thank you. Although I now have to contain each button in a parent div and style that parent with a new class selector, I actually am becoming very fond of this approach. The parent div is the 'hotspot' for the button that stays in place. When hovered, it nudges the child `a` element inside (but still within the hotspot). It just makes more sense than the way I was approaching the situation.

Comment: Here is a link to the webpage that I am currently working on. I can't say how long this link will remain relevant. http://poppysinger.xtreemhost.com/cards.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you tray change position property? fixed for example:

```
a:hover {
 position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS3 delay to nullify this problem

```
a { 
display: block;
position: relative; 
width:40px;
height:30px;
}

a:hover {
top: -5px; left: -5px;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 5px 5px 2px; 
-webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
}
```

Comment: I tried this per your advice. All it did was delay the time it took for the box-shadow to appear. Albeit a neat way to fade-in the shadow, not really in the park of what I'm looking for.